# Is it possible to import variables from __init__.py in views.py?

Tags: python, flask, import, module, python-3.5

I have a flask application in which I do some analysis of some data and draw some graphs based on that data. However up until now I have been performing the analysis and drawing of graphs in my views.py file, in my index method. This is not very good, as each time I perform a "refresh" of in my browser it will redo the entire analysis and draw the graphs all over.

My project structure is as follows:

```
Data Analysis/
  - app/
    - static/
    - templates/
      - base.html
      - index.html 
    - __init__.py
    - models.py
    - views.py
  - venv/
  - run.py
  - config.py
```

I thought of moving my data analysis to my __init__.py module as this would result in only calculating the required data once the application is run, instead of rerunning it on every refresh. The hurdle I've run into is actually importing the data I need in my views.py module from my __init__.py module.

How is this done?

I've tried the following:

## __init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def do_data_analysis():
    #... lots of calculations

    return data

VALUES = do_data_analysis()
```

## views.py

```
from app import app, models, __init__ #does not work
from __init__ import VALUES #does not work
import VALUES #does not work
from app import VALUES # does not work
VALUES = __init__.VALUES #does not work
```

Is there another and maybe more proper way of doing this?

## EDIT:

I've managed to get it working by creating a module (`data_analysis.py`) in which I am performing all my data analysis. This does also mean that in my `__init__.py` I have removed my data analysis and I now instead have the following in my `view.py`:

```
from app import data_analysis
```

Now I can do:

```
GPSVALUES = data_analysis.VALUES
#do something with the values..
```

<s>It does however seem to be running the script twice. First at start-up of my `run.py`. And then again when the first request comes in</s>. It seems to be running the script only on starting the `run.py`. And if the page is refreshed it doesn't rerun the script which is what I wanted in the first place. Therefore I think I'm gonna go with this solution unless no other solution comes in. (I will add an answer as soon as I've done some more testing)

Comment: Your premise is flawed. There's nothing about having code in `__init__` that means it will only be run once; you can get the same effect by putting it a module level in views.py.

Comment: If I were to make a secondary module for my data analysis in the same folder level as my views.py I would require to run it somewhere. If I were to run it in my views.py, it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: Yes it does, if you run it at module level.

Comment: You're gonna have to explain what that means.. or at least point me towards where I can find the solution

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
import __init__
VALUES = __init__.VALUES
```

---

```
from app import app, models, __init__
```

fails because you can not import from `app` if it is not in your scope.

```
from __init__ import VALUES
```

fails because `VAULES` is a variable and not a module/ function.

```
import VALUES
```

fails because, well... there is no `VALUES` module.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work. I get `ImportError: No module named '__init__'`

Comment: Didn't expect `import __init__` to work but it did!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
from app import VALUES
```

This might work.

If you want to do the data analysis only once in your application, give a read on these flask decorators,

- [before_first_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request)
- [before_app_first_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_first_request)

Comment: `from app import VALUES` doesn't seem to work either. How would I go about using those two decorators, I've done some searching, but can't really find any examples.

Comment: what error do you get for `import`?.. and for those decorators, add `@app.before_first_request` above the function declaration. Adding this would invoke the function once before processing the first request that comes to the application. Note that the function decorated as such cannot return anything.

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'GPSVALUES'` (I've renamed it does to the use of multiple types of values).

Answer (score 1):

No doubt this answer comes a bit late.

It also looks like the answer was found, but the reasons for it a little obscure, leaving room for some clarity as to how `__init__.py` can aid in organizing expansive projects, for one, by allowing modules within directories to discretize categories of functions (into modules) which can then be referenced through one name (the name of the folder the modules are in), leaving only remembering the names of functions in the bunch of files gathered in that folder, and properly importing them under that name.

Adding a couple of lines to `__init__.py` will configure it to expose the modules contained within the folder it naturally turns into a package, namely, in this case, the folder 'app'.

To `__init__.py` in the folder 'app', try adding:

```
from .models import <name of defs to expose>
from .views import <name of defs to expose>
```

Then, in `views.py`, the module into which the imports should go, replace `from app import app, models, __init__` with:

```
app import app
from app import app <list of exposed fns needed here>
```

Instead of trying to import `__init__.py` anywhere, create a module within app which contains functions you want to expose through `__init__.py` to the rest of the application, using only the reference to 'app'.

Basically, all that happens here is the module names are made transparent and their exposed functions are grouped under the folder name. `__init__.py` makes this possible by turning the folder under which it exists into a package. That package can be put on the PYTHONPATH, or references to it within import statements can be done in pathname -relative, or -absolute fashion.